# What verb was cut off here (implied verb)?

Tags: verbs, food, omission

I would like some more context on what is being said in cooking instructions for Takoyaki.　On the ingredients list, サラダ油 is listed, and it has this footnote:

> ごま油を一割混ぜると香ばしい風味に！

To provide some context to my question, a phrase like 銀河に願いを from Kirby Super Star trails off without indicating what verb the "wish" is an object to; I still do not know what verb is supposed to be there, but one can figure out it relates to making a wish.

Looking back at the footnote, I know that the verb dropped relates to adding the aromatic flavor to the takoyaki when it is cooked (the oil is applied to the タコ焼き機 before the batter is poured in), **but what verb in specific is dropped?**

If someone knows a resource of common omissions like these, I would also appreciate that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thinking of cases like this as some specific verb being omitted may be the wrong track to begin with - in most cases. Here I see no other option than なる

Comment: ...Any ideas on "銀河に願いを"?

Comment: @BigRigz Like I said thinking some specific verb is being omitted is the wrong track. 'Wish Upon a Star' is 星に願いを. If you really really want some specific verb, maybe 乗せて or 言って

Comment: 「ごま油を一割混ぜると香ばしい風味に仕上がります！」でもいいよね。「星に願いを」... 何だろう！？「こめて」とかかな？「かけて」かも？？やっぱり「星に願いを。」で終わりで、動詞要らないよね